# Initialize hive in flutter initState method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Rather than calling some async function to get document directory and initialize hive database inside `main` function, I want to keep things as abstract as possible. I want to implement `Hive.init(..)` inside a provider service and calling that service during `initState()` method. In this way my `main` method does not care or even does not know what database I am using, rather than calling the provider service. The implementation should be like this.

> service.dart

```
class Service extends ChangeNotifier {
  ....

  Future<void> init() async {
    Directory dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);

 ....
```

> view.dart

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => Service(),
      child: _MyPageContent(),
    );
  }
}

.....

class _MyPageContent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  __MyPageContentState createState() => __MyPageContentState();
}

class __MyPageContentState extends State<_MyPageContent> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<Service>(context, listen: false).init();
  }
  ....
....
```

However, this is not working. The error I am getting as

```
HiveError (HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box.)
```

The reason may be `Service.init()` method, being an async one, is getting called inside `initState()` by the time `build` method performs it's task. So is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: the parent uses the Service and you are initializing it from a child? initialize service inside the `MyPage`

Answer (score 1):

Give the service a function to execute when it loads the Hive

```
class Service extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<void> init(Function onDoneInitializing) async {
    Directory dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);
    onDoneInitializing();
  }
}
```

change the content according to the state set by the function you gave to the `Service.init`

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  bool doneInitializing = false;
  Service _service;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _service = Service();
    _service.init(() {
      setState(() {
        doneInitializing = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return doneInitializing
        ? ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => _service,
      child: _MyPageContent(),
    )
        : CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `state` class and it seems to be working.

```
class __MyPageContentState extends State<_MyPageContent> {

  bool _init = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<Service>(context, listen: false).init()
    .then((_) => setState(() => _init = true));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_init)
      return MyPreciousWidget(...);
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
....
```